# Is there similar way to pagefactory (iOSXcuitFindBy/AndroidFindby) to handle dynamic element identifiers?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mobile, appium, page-factory, findby

I have a hybrid app, which have the same features on iOS and Android. I want to use one repository to automate both platform. How can I identify the element for both platform without a if-else statement?

```
   public class LoginPage extends BasePage {

    String alertmsg;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "dynamic identifier....")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy**(xpath= "//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[`name == \""+alertmsg+"\"`]")**
    public WebElement alertBanner;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id=\"username\"]")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeTextField")
    public WebElement usernameInputField;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id=\"password\"]")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeSecureTextField")
    public WebElement passwordInputField;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@text=\"Log in\"]")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='Log in' or @name='Anmelden']")
    public WebElement loginBtn;

    public void peformLogin(String username, String password){
        usernameInputField.click();
        usernameInputField.sendKeys(username);
        passwordInputField.click();
        passwordInputField.sendKeys(password);
        loginBtn.click();
    }

    public void setAlertBannerTxt(String  bannerTxt){
        alertmsg = bannerTxt;
    }


}
```

I tried to pass the concatenated xpath to the @iOSXCUITFindBy annotation, but it won't work, since the value is not present at the instantiation.

Comment: you probably want to use dependency injection here and have two types of page objects (or really just classes of locators, one for each platform type) that implement the same interface.

Comment: just classes of locators, that implements the same class